# Multiple handling functions in if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I was wondering if multiple handling functions in an `if` statement is bad practice or hated?

**Example:**

```
if(empty($employee) OR empty($project) OR empty($streetName) OR empty($zipCode) OR empty($city)){
    $error = true;
}
```

Comment: Let says that there are better way to do things. But, as always, do what works for you.

Comment: Could you possibly point me in a direction, where i can read/learn about a better way?

Comment: Not exactly sure if it will answer the question, but Clean Code is a good read.

Comment: I'm new to programming and would like to learn the good habits and clean coding, before I end up learning the bad ways and habits. It would be really nice if someone could point my in the right direction. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: *point my in the right direction* http://www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Why would it be? There are other ways to do it but they shouldn't be abused as they hinder code readability.

For instance using `array_reduce`:

```
if (array_reduce(array($employee, $project, $streetName, $zipCode), function ($a, $b) {
   if (!$a || !$b) {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
})) {{
    $error = true;
}
```

Isn't it cleaner? No? That's why we have `OR` statements.

In programming in general, there is a load of ways to achieve the same thing. The only time you should even consider sacrificing readability is when performance is at stake.

Comment: if you need an example about "is this 'new way' express a clear intent about what you need to do, or just make it hard to read", use something like: `if (sizeof($inputs) !== sizeof(array_filter($inputs))) {`. That `array_reduce` example is hurting me. :D

Comment: I'm a javascript dev, I'm not extremely familiar with the fancy stuff. Incidentally, the reduce could look quite clean in JS: `[employee, project, empty, zipCode].reduce((a,b)=>!!(a&&b))`